# Править прошивку термопринтера

Tags: c, com-порт

Есть прошивка для термопринтера которую нужно поправить. Принтер подключен через COM порт. Если с винды печатать пробную страницу при flow control= none или XON\Xof все печатает хорошо, если выбрать аппаратное управление потоком, то начинает печатать ахинею или вообще не печатает.

Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть и с чем это может быть связано?

Windows 7(x64), tg2480-h

подключение реализовано при помощи виртуального ком порта, чип STM32f207
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите ОС, модель принтера, версии драйверов и все остальное необходимое для поиска решения

Comment: Если вы не хотите предоставлять более полную информацию, то получается вы не помогаете нам помогать вам ...

Comment: @Kromster, он же дополнил?

Comment: @Qwertiy было бы здорово, если бы дополнение было более информативным - в частности ОС (и битность), описание железа реализующего COM порт (если оно нестандартное), полной название модели принтера и его прошивки/ревизии, версия и описание установленных драверов, программа из которой ведется печать .. Согласитесь, что текущее дополнение несколько коротковато?

Comment: Еще вопрос, как вы хотите поправить прошивку, судя по меткам, на языке C ?

Comment: @Kromster да на С

Answer (score 0):

Принтер начинает печатать ахинею, потому что он начинает принимать с ком-порта ахинею. Параметры порта должны полностью совпадать на обеих сторонах, иначе приёмник не сможет верно определить стартовый бит, бит четности (если он присутствует), стоп-бит. Следовательно, он будет принимать неверные данные. Если вы хотите изменить параметры ком-порта, то вы должны это сделать и в прошивке. Включили аппаратное управление потоком на ПК - включите его и в принтере.

Comment: Так и делаю,  по мануалу написано что нужно уснатовисть 8-9 биты регистара USART->CR3 в 1 что бы включить апаратное управление я так и сделал,на устройстве и в настройках порта поставил апаратное управление (HARDWARE) пробная странница не идет на печать всеравно

Comment: Как я понял, на STM у вас промежуточное устройство, которое, скорее всего, принимает данные с ПК по USB, являясь при этом виртуальным ком-портом. Далее по RS-232 это устройство передаёт данные принтеру. Вот тут нужно проверить совпадение параметров порта (вашего устройства и принтера). Если я неправ, опишите подробнее архитектуру взаимодействия ваших устройств.

Comment: с ПК стандартными средствами  отправляется запрос на пробную печать (отправляет буфер данных на принтер) который должен прожечь эти все даные на бумаге, а он просто стоит  и не печатает

Comment: Данных недостаточно. Опишите подробно, как соединяется ваше устройство на STM с ПК и как оно соединяется с принтером.